# Error installing Intel network drivers on Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, drivers

I'm trying to install LAN and WLAN drivers on a Thinkpad T430. The Intel installer succeeds as does selecting the driver from device manager. However, the status for both devices is "Windows could not load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31) - An object ID was not found in the file."

- The devices are "Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205" and "Intel(R)
  82579LM Gigabit Network Connection".
- I'm getting this problem after upgrading from Windows 8.1 (x64)
- Using driver versions 15.18.0.1 for Centrino and 12.9.15.0 for Gigabit.
- I've tried restarting
- ThinkVantage system update doesn't work without an internet connection
- I'm not using a VPN

Comment: [See if this Microsoft fixit helps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/hardware_device_problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your GB wired adapter, head directly to [Intel's download cetner](https://downloadcenter.intel.com) and get the latest ProSet drivers from them.  The current release is v20.3.

Direct Link: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25016/Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10

For your Wifi, there are no Windows 10 "Centrino" drivers, but the generic Intel PROSet/Wireless Software package will probably (hopefully) work. It's current version is 18.20.

Direct Link: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25279/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-for-Windows-10

Comment: Both said they installed successfully but after restarting, neither made a difference

Comment: Ah, I forgot to uninstall the drivers before I reinstalled. Thanks for the help.